# Data is not sitting right in tableview in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, struct

I have a view controller which has a tableView and a button. When the user presses the button, I show them a popup to choose between the button and  the textField. When one of them is chosen, I add it to my tableView in header, and add some rows under that section based on its type. If it is a textField I add 3, if it is a button I add 2.

I have a struct which defines my model:

```
struct CreationModel {
    var typeName:String?
    var content:Content
}
struct Content {
    var Hint:String?
    var Query:String?
    var Text:String?
    var Label:String?
    var Kind:String?
}
```

And I defined this struct in my VC like:

```
    var itemsInTable = [CreationModel]()
```

1. In the picture below you can see the vc when user opens this vc.
   [image: This is the vc when user open this vc]
2. In the picture below you can see the popUp where the user has to chose.
   [image: This is the popUp that user should chose]
3. In the picture below you can see the tableView after  the user selected the textField for 3 times.
   [image: this the tableView after user selected textField for 3 time]
4. In the picture below, here the 4th textField is added.
   [image: the 4th textField is added here]

**In the picture number 4 you can see that the data from section one is places in section 4! 
Does anybody know what is going on here and what am I doing wrong?**

I also add my tableView's code and the button's code below:

```
        @IBAction func addRow(_ sender: Any) {
            let popUp:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "انتخاب کنید", message: "چه پارامتری باید اضافه بشه؟", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let TextFieldAction = UIAlertAction(title: "textField", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
    //            self.itemsInTable.append("textField")
                self.itemsInTable.append(CreationModel(typeName: "textField", content: Content(Hint: nil, Query: nil, Text: nil, Label: nil, Kind: nil)))

                self.numberOfSections = self.numberOfSections + 1
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            let ButtonAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Button", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
    //            self.itemsInTable.append("Button")
                self.itemsInTable.append(CreationModel(typeName: "Button", content: Content(Hint: nil, Query: nil, Text: nil, Label: nil, Kind: nil))) 

                self.numberOfSections = self.numberOfSections + 1
                self.tableView.reloadData()


            }

            let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Print", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
    //            self.itemsInTable.append("Button")
    //            self.numberOfRows = self.numberOfRows + 1
    //            self.tableView.reloadData()
                print("⚠️⚠️⚠️⚠️⚠️⚠️⚠️⚠️\n\n⚠️⚠️\n⚠️\n\n\n\(self.itemsInTable)")
            }
            popUp.addAction(TextFieldAction)
            popUp.addAction(ButtonAction)
            popUp.addAction(CancelAction)
            self.present(popUp, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 70
        }
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return numberOfSections
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if itemsInTable[section].typeName == "textField"
            {
                return 3
            }


             else if itemsInTable[section].typeName == "Button"
            {
                return 2
            }
            return 0
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionCell") as! CreationTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
    //        print(itemsInTable[indexPath.row])
            if itemsInTable[section].typeName == "textField"
            {
                cell.Btn.isHidden = true
                cell.Txt.isHidden = false
                cell.Txt.text = "textField : \(section)"
                return cell
            }
            else if itemsInTable[section].typeName == "Button"
            {
                cell.Btn.isHidden = false
                cell.Txt.isHidden = true
                cell.Btn.setTitle("Button \(section)", for: .normal)
                cell.Btn.isEnabled = false
                cell.Btn.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
                cell.Btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                return cell
            }
            //        cell.mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            return cell
        }



     func tableView(_ tableView: UI

TableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RowCell") as! RowTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        print(itemsInTable[indexPath.section])
        if itemsInTable[indexPath.section].typeName == "textField"
        {
            switch (indexPath.section,indexPath.row) {

            case (indexPath.section,0):
//                if itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Hint?.isEmpty == false
//                {
//                    cell.txt.text = itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Hint
//                }
                cell.TitleLbl.text = "Placeholder"
                cell.EntityLbl.text = "Hint"
                cell.txt.placeholder = "Placeholder"
                itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Hint = cell.txt.text
                return cell
            case (indexPath.section,1):
//                if itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Query?.isEmpty == false
//                {
//                    cell.txt.text = itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Query

    //                }
                    cell.TitleLbl.text = "پارامتر URL"
                    cell.EntityLbl.text = "Query"
                    cell.txt.placeholder = "پارامتر URL"
                    itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Query = cell.txt.text
                    return cell
                case (indexPath.section,2):
    //                if itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Text?.isEmpty == false
    //                {
    //                    cell.txt.text = itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Text
    //                }
                    cell.TitleLbl.text = "متن"
                    cell.EntityLbl.text = "Text"
                    cell.txt.placeholder = "متن"
                    itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Text = cell.txt.text
                    return cell

                default:
                    return cell
                }
            }
            else if  itemsInTable[indexPath.section].typeName == "Button"
            {
                switch (indexPath.section,indexPath.row) {

                case (indexPath.section,0):
    //                if itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Label?.isEmpty == false
    //                {

    //                    cell.txt.text = itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Label
    //                }
                    cell.TitleLbl.text = "متن"
                    cell.EntityLbl.text = "Label"
                    cell.txt.placeholder = "متن روی دکمه"
                    itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Label = cell.txt.text
                    return cell
                case (indexPath.section,1):
    //                if itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Kind?.isEmpty == false
    //                {
    //                    cell.txt.text = itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Kind
    //                }
                    cell.TitleLbl.text = "نوع عملیات"
                    cell.EntityLbl.text = "Kind"
                    cell.txt.placeholder = "اکسل، پای چارت"
                    itemsInTable[indexPath.section].content.Kind = cell.txt.text
                    return cell
                default:
                    return cell
                }
            }
            return cell

        }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be setting cell.txt.text in your cellForRowAt() method?

Comment: as you can see there are some lines that I have commented in cellForRowAt(). as they are commented ,then if I type anything in any textfield in any section in any row, it should not impact the other section or rows!! but it changes the other section's textField real-time

Comment: Your answer is confusing. For the code that represent those screenshots, are those lines of code commented out or not? I am assuming they were not and that is where your problem is: in those if-statements you are only setting (or rather changing) cell.txt.text if that itemsInTable entry is empty. And so because of cell re-use, the cell will show any previous text if not.

Comment: could you please show me the code! I'm confused

Comment: This blog post describes the cell re-use process very well: https://fluffy.es/solve-duplicated-cells/

Comment: this is exactly what I've been trying to say :) thank you